# API Request Distribution and Security

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, api

I am working on an experiment in distributed API requests. I am building a website in PHP that will allow my users to make requests on the behalf of the server. By doing this I should be able to distribute the requests to all users and allow my application to remain scalable even with large amounts of traffic.

My end goal is to have the browser make an API request, parse the response and submit the parsed data to my server. This *should* eliminate a performance bottleneck from which my application is currently suffering. However, I am having issues with how to build this system.

**Here is how I have envisioned the system working:**

1. User visits website
2. API request queue is loaded from a list of work
3. Browser makes multiple API requests from work queue and parses response
4. Browser sends parsed data to server via AJAX
5. Server updates old data, adds a timestamp, and removes request from the work queue
6. After predetermined TTL work is added to queue again and process repeats

**Here are my concerns:**

- The API requests are not being made on the same domain as my server. I understand that this will present a problem when requesting the data from the user's browser (because of same-origin policy). I have looked into using a proxy PHP file but this, too, has raised some concerns - see my next bullet.
- Distributing the parsing is only part of the problem, the other issue is throttling my requests. I am limited in the number of requests I can make per second, and it is causing an issue with scalability. I am afraid that by creating a proxy file to make the requests I am still limited by the request throttling since the requests are technically still originating from my server via the proxy file.
- Since the browser is parsing the response and sending it to my server, it is conceivable that someone could inject malicious data into the server via the AJAX call.

**And finally my questions:**

- Based on my requirements, is using a proxy PHP file the best method in making these requests?
- If using a proxy file *is* the best method, would I still be limited by the request throttling or are the requests (and consequently the throttling limits) passed to the client?
- Other than the standard security measures (escaping strings, stripping slashes and using SSL) can you think of any other precautions to be made in the AJAX-to-server communications?
- Has anyone done this already, and if so is there an example that I would be able to follow? I have searched around and I must be wording my searches incorrectly since all my results are unrelated to my requirements.
- And finally a few optional opinion questions... What are your thoughts on this methodology? Is this structure fatally flawed? Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing to resolve this problem is by using JSONP and loading the content via the clients browser. Here is the flow:

- Client visits site and receives a list of API request URLs. These URLs are embedded with script tags (to get around the same-origin policy). With the JSONP method the data is returned as a callback function containing a data object.
- JSONP data is then parsed client side in a private function to avoid manipulation by the client and sent to an AJAX handler. I also added escapes and validation in the handler for extra security.
- Handler submits the parsed data to MySQL along with a timestamp. If insert was made, the work queue is updated for the specified entry. Periodically a CRON job runs a cleanup routine to update the queue and set it to a cached array. New URLs are pulled from this array and process repeats.

After doing some testing I found out the following about my questions:

- Proxy files simply make the request on the behalf of the client. Because the server *is* making the request this will still be subject to throttling.
- The only methods that I found that will make the request from the client's browser window is JSONP, CORS and WebSockets. CORS and Websockets are not available in every browser, so I didn't go that route. JSONP has a content-length limit but I'm not parsing lots of data per client, just a lot of data as a whole - this is why I chose JSONP. Parsing iframes will also work, but I was unable to find a solution that worked in most browsers. Eventually I would like to add multiple forms of getting the data to ensure that the most users possible are sharing in the distribution.
- There are many APIs that support JSONP and CORS! I was surprised how many, actually. It can get a little tricky when an API doesn't support it, but I will cross that bridge when I come to it.
- I would still like to know if anyone thinks this method is fatally flawed in some way, but I feel much more comfortable using something as established as JSONP instead of some custom scripted solution.